# Problems installing django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to install django by acessing the directory that contains setup.py using
    `cd [Path to Django]` and then `python setup.py install`. But the following is shown on terminal:

> running install
>    Checking .pth file support in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/
>   error: can't create or remove files in install directory
>
> The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
>   installation directory:
>
> [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages>/test-easy-install-5264.pth'
>
> The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
>   the distutils default setting) was:
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/
>
> Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
>   installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
>   as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
>   access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
>   directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
>   variable.
>
> For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
>   documentation at:
>
> https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html
>
> Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.

I am new to using Ubuntu and Python, so i am a little lost. Can someone help?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Be superuser.  `sudo pip install django`.  Or use virtualenv.

Comment: virtualenv might be the best bet.  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv